# onkeyup function with PHP argument

Tags: php, javascript

How to add PHP in an onkeyup function?

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="if($_SESSION['user'] == TRUE) do.this else do.that">
```

Comment: Whatever your thought is behind this ... uh ... thing, please drop it immediately and open another question.

Comment: You can call a function that connects to server via AJAX

Comment: I uses AJAX to receive some data for $_SESSION['user'].

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is this:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="<?php if($_SESSION['user'] == TRUE) ?> do.this <?php else ?> do.that">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" <?php echo $_SESSION['user']==TRUE ? "onkeyup=('Do This')" : "onkeyup=('Do That')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.
Php is server side programming language, javascript is client side (but it can be server side too :) but not in you case)

But to solve you issue you need
in header include jquery (just for easy ajax calling)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

add script which will call server

```
    <script>
    function callServer(){
$.ajax({  url: "serverSide.php" })
.done(function() {
  alert("Server called");
});
    }
    </script>
```

then  add event handler for keyup

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="callServer()">
```

then create serverSide.php and add your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Add PHP tags:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="if(<?php $_SESSION['user'] == TRUE ?>) do.this else do.that">
```

Comment: <input type="text" onkeyup="if(<?php $_SESSION['user'] == TRUE ?>) do.this else do.that">

is this what you mean. still wont work.

Comment: Yes I mean this, but I wasn't able to write it properly on my iphone...

Comment: but there should be echo: if(<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] == TRUE ?>)